# Why @RequestHeader does not work with @MessageMapping?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, react-native, spring-security, spring-websocket

My goal is to get the RequestHeader e.g `Authorization` from a message published by Stomp.

The flow

```
1. Subscribe
Front End <-> /topic/javainuse

2. Publish Message
Front End <-> /app/chat.newUser
```

The Spring Boot WebSocket's source code

```
  @MessageMapping("/chat.newUser")
  @SendTo("/topic/javainuse")
  public WebSocketChatMessage newUser(@RequestHeader(value = "Authorization") String authorization, WebSocketChatMessage message, SimpMessageHeaderAccessor headerAccessor) {
    System.out.println("Authorization: " + authorization);
    headerAccessor.getSessionAttributes().put("username", message.getSender()); // dependency of WebSocketChatEventListener to handle SessionDisconnectEvent.
    return message;
  }
```

The Front End's source code, written in JavaScript

```
  const publish = () => {
    stompClient.publish({
      destination: '/app/chat.newUser',
      body: JSON.stringify({
        sender: 'User A',
        type: 'newUser',
      }),
      headers: {
        Authorization: 'Bearer a',
      },
      skipContentLengthHeader: true,
    });
  };
```

My expected result is it will print out the Authorization's key value.

My actual result is

```
Authorization: {"sender":"User A","type":"newUser"}
```

==================================================

Related question but not the main topic

==================================================

I am worried that my practice for the RestController is wrong since my practice can't be applied to WebSocket:

1. What are the advantages of using Spring Security over manual `@RequestHeader` annotation?
   Currently, I use @RequestHeader inside a RestController e.g

```
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<Object> something(@RequestHeader(value = "Authorization) String authorization) {
  boolean isValid = customValidatorService.isValid(authorization.split(" ")[1]);

  // do something
  if (isValid === false) {}
  else (isValid === true) {}
  ...
}
```

2. Why should you use Spring Security to handle RestController and WebSocket instead of using the `@RequestHeader(value = "Authorization")` annotation and a Custom Validator Service?
3. If you protect the websocket endpoint, is validating `e.g by do a sql eury SELECT session from a table` for every published message sent to a `@MessageMapping` a correct practice?

Disclaimer: I have not use Spring Security at all.

Comment: That the security is handled for you instead you rolling your own security framework with less features and more bugs then Spring Security. The header you set is `'Bearer a' what you are sending is the body.

Comment: Shouldn't `@RequestHeader(value = "Authorization")` get the key's value? I did it with REST endpoint which use `@RequestMapping`. What do you mean by less features and more bugs? Could you please explain how Spring Security handle a REST POST endpoint mapping `let say that I use a session, and I store the session inside a sql database`?

Comment: How you store a session or even using a session doesn't matter. What is import is that you should use a framework that adds security, instead o trying to create your own. Spring Security can perfectly handle a header with a bearer token to do authentication/authorization. So unless you want to write custom logic in each method and to add all the security features a framework provide, don't. I don't see what you are printing (or where), so unless you are doing something else it should just print the value. If it doesn't you must either be printing something else, or do other things.

Comment: Also with `@MessageMapping` you should use `@Header` and not `@RequestHeader`. The messaging is agnostic about the transport being used (could be mail, jms, HTTP etc.).

Comment: @M.Deinum well noted. I want to clarify, do you mean by using Spring Security it will acts as an Interceptor for every HTTP methods? Currently I wrote my Authorization on every HTTP method e.g the ones that use `@RequestMapping`, I do find them to be smelly because it's just a copy and paste 2 lines of code. Is that one of the purpose of using Spring Security?

Comment: It will act exactly as that with configurable security rules, roles etc.